# Treating the contents of string as a vite module

Tags: vite

I have a use case where I'd like to be able to have `vite` transform the `html` content of `srcDoc` in order to load other modules from my project.

```
// frame-functions.js
export function frameAdd (a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

```
// frame.jsx
const srcDoc = `
  <script type="module">
    import {frameAdd} from "./frame-functions"
    console.log(frameAdd(2, 2))
  </script>
`

function App () {
  return <iframe srcDoc={srcDoc} />
}
```

This will work for `development` but fails in `production` because `frame.js` has been re-written to a hashed value like `frame-Cyguhgs-.js`. This happens with a template string `srcDoc` or if I import the `html` file with a `?raw` queryString.

Is there a way I can get process my `srcDoc` snippet with vite's `transformIndexHtml`?